# Is this 'implementation' of a builder pattern good design

Tags: java, design, design-patterns

```
public class MyButton{
    public MyButton(){}
    public MyButton setIcon(Icon icon){return this;}
    public MyButton setText(String text){return this;}
}
```

And used like:

```
MyButton testButton = new MyButton()
    .setIcon(MyIcon)
    .setText("MyText");
```

I know its not a true implementation of the builder pattern, but is there something inherently wrong with this design?

Comment: What is the intended usage? What should happen when SetIcon or SetText are called multiple times?

Comment: Calling setIcon/setText would just override whatever you set it to before. Basically it works like a normal buttons code ie:

`MyButton test = new MyButton();
test.setIcon();  
test.setText();`

Comment: That's not an implementation of the builder pattern, but an example of fluent setters. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345001/is-it-bad-practice-to-make-a-setter-return-this

Comment: @COMEFROM could you please make that an answer, as that was exactly what I was looking for. The answers in that thread answer my question. Or could someone flag it as a duplicate of the link above?

Comment: I can't flag this question as a duplicate since the other question is from another site. I'm also a little hesitant to write an answer since I don't really have any experience of using that pattern. I've used the `foo.withSomething(bar)` to make a clear difference between traditional setters and fluent methods but that's really the only thing I have to say about the issue.

Comment: The biggest problem with the design is that you're not enforcing that all the required data is provided to the object. It's possible to create a MyButton that has neither icon nor text.

Comment: @Doval The code above was used as an example, in practice the MyButton class gets sent a width and height. so having an empty button would be possible, and is intended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @COMEFROM [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345001/is-it-bad-practice-to-make-a-setter-return-this) answered the question perfectly.
The style used here is called a [Fluent Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4493253/5620357) mentions a convention which is inline with standard java convention and doesn't theoretically interfere with [jvm optimizations and javabean compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1365710/5620357)

Answer (score 3):

*Is it the builder pattern?* As Euphoric explained, no, it is not. A Builder is a **separate** class which has the purpose to create an instance of a **different** class.

*Is there anything wrong with the design?* That depends. Does your application allow buttons which don't have a text and/or icon? If yes, then this pattern is perfectly acceptable. If no, you might want to consider writing a `ButtonBuilder` class which throws an exception (or at least an `assert`) when you call `buttonBuilder.build()` before setting all required properties.

Comment: @COMEFROM answered the question perfectly in the comments below the question. I called it a builder pattern for lack of a better name, however calling it a fluent interface would have been much more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

The core part of Builder patter is the build part, not the fluent syntax part.

If your class is not building another class, then it shouldn't be called builder.

In your case, I would call it "fluent property setting" or something similar.

Comment: Well, I didn't really know what else to call it. Anyway, is anything inherently wrong with the design?

Comment: @Rulasmur What design? You are just setting properties using fluent syntax. This is more stylistic choice than design choice.